# Statistics of unit usage?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2 some units are used more often than others. Of course it depends on many things, including tier, regular/spell-caster, the race of the opponent, etc.

Are there any statistics of unit usage in Starcraft 2? For example; saying on average how many units of a certain type are produced in a match, or in how many games at least one is produced?

Comment: curious why the close vote, I think this is an interesting question, but a more interesting question would be if advanced statistics exist for build order usage rather than # of units produced.

Comment: Are you talking about global stats for all (ladder) games played?  Activision would be the only one to have that, and it would either be well-known (if publicly available) or it's not released.

Comment: @NickT I doubt if there is place with whole stats. However, any dataset would be of my interest.

Comment: I would guess the close vote is because something like this would probably fall under the "too localized" category. Say I'm zerg playing against terran and I'm going for mutas, but if I scout and see a quick double gas, then it's probably going to mean cloak banshee which would inflate the number of produced overseers and queens. Most unit compositions are built based on what is scouted to counter the opponent (endless cycle by the way).

Comment: @Sorean No, I am not searching on a strategic guide, rather - just curious which units are underused (e.g. never saw Battlecruiser for real).

Comment: @yx the only reason I could imagine to close this question is it might be considered 'unanswerable'. But frankly I think thats almost (depends) a good quality for a quesion. It makes people think. Problem is you get swamped with low quality answers that ruin the point of the site. Meh. Nothings perfect.

Comment: @Sorean, such statistics would of course depend on the matchup and be subjected to influence by the shifting metagame, but would still be somewhat insightful into resource distribution. Such an analysis of high tier play would be difficult as both MLG and GSL no longer release replays publicly, even if there was a program that could tell how many of each unit were built during a game. Essentially unanswerable as far as I can tell.

Comment: Battlecruisers have been used in professional play (seen it a few times in the GSL), but as you mentioned it is rare for it to occur. I just don't think this question is truly able to be answered in it's current form.

Answer (score 5):

I think the closest you'll get will be [SC2gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/home).

Open up a replay in it and select the chart type *Builds/Tech Stat* and then check only the *Units* checkbox.

[image: Units built during a game]

As far as I can see you can only do that one replay at a time, so getting an overview might be very, very tiresome. If you can program, maybe you can use the [plugin interface](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/features/plugin-interface)?

Comment: This is a great program with a lot of cool features but pretty much completely irrelevant to the OP's request.

Comment: @Decency: I pointed the OP in the wrong feature direction. Now it shouldn't be completely irrelevant but "just" bothersome

Answer (score 0):

There is [GGTracker](http://ggtracker.com/).

In particular, they have API for downloading very detailed description of games (each unit produced, etc): http://ggtracker.com/api